# Printing odd/even pages using system dialogue ubuntu

Tags: printing, 17.04, pdf, system, plugins

I am printing (Basically saving to file) a pdf. I want to print only the odd/even pages from a PDF. In the printing dialogue box which appears I see only 3 options in the range

- All Pages
- Current Page
- Pages: (Specify a range)

Is there a way (without manually typing individual odd/even numbers comma separated) to accomplish this?

Is there any plugin sort of thing or alternative method to accomplish this?

I am using Ubuntu 17.04. I am attaching the screenshot of dialogue box below.

[image]

Comment: To add to the other answers, one really annoying caveat is that "Reverse" on the first tab is applied before "Only print." With an even number of total pages, selecting "Only print odd sheets" and "Reverse" will actually print even pages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure what program you are using to view and print the PDF file, so I just went with Ubuntu's default PDF viewer, **Evince**.

You might need to install a "print to file" printer on your system.  I installed **cups-pdf**, by typing this in a terminal window:

```
sudo apt install cups-pdf
```

Then when you open a PDF file, and go to print it, choose the **PDF** printer option.  The print dialogue window will have the **Only print** option, under the **Page Setup** tab, where you can choose odd or even pages.

It will put the resulting file in your home directory under a PDF directory (**~/PDF**), where you can rename and/or move it later.

[image]

Comment: I am using document viewer. Even after installing the cups-pdf. It is not showing as the screenshot you have provided

Comment: Note that if you use custom page range, "odd" counts 1 as the first page in that range, even if that page number is even. Similarly, "even" starts from the second page even if that page number is odd.

Answer (score 6):

In the <kbd>Page Setup</kbd> tab, there should be a drop-down menu labelled `Only print: All sheets`.

[image: print dialog - page setup]

<sup>Screenshot taken from Evince (PDF Document Viewer) on Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity Desktop.</sup>

You can select `Only print: Even sheets` or `Only print: Odd sheets` there.

---

PS: You should note that the print settings you change normally persist and do not only apply for the current print job and then get reset. This can lead to surprises when printing something later without checking those settings again. I personally found it useful to [prevent Evince from saving the print settings](https://askubuntu.com/q/679705/367990).